# Custom processor build failing due to Jackson dependency

Tags: maven, jackson, apache-nifi

I've created a custom processor which uses jackson json library and the unit-test works fine.

I'm a bit confused about which project/module to build to create the target nar.

The pom.xml of the processor (maven)project is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>com.datalake</groupId>
<artifactId>CDCNiFi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        </dependency>        
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-mock</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
<artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

The pom.xml of the nar(maven)project is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.datalake</groupId>
        <artifactId>CDCNiFi</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-nar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <source.skip>true</source.skip>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datalake</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The parent(?) pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.datalake</groupId>
    <artifactId>CDCNiFi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors</module>
        <module>nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-nar</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Now when I try to build the parent or the processor project, I get the jackson error, I'm unable to understand why the jackson library is not getting loaded :

```
E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-proces
sors>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-st
aging-maven-plugin
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-proces
sors ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-N
iFiCDCPoC-processors\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ nifi-NiFiCDCPoC
-processors ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ nifi-NiFiCDCPoC
-processors ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ nifi-NiFiC
DCPoC-processors ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ nifi-NiFiCDCPoC
-processors ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to E:\
NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPo
C-processors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[65,3
3] error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.core does not exist
[ERROR] E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPo
C-processors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[66,3
7] error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
[ERROR] E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPo
C-processors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[250,
10] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class MyProcessor
E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-proces
sors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[250,42] erro
r: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class MyProcessor
E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-proces
sors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[279,21] erro
r: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 5 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.179 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-06T21:26:33+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/560M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
2:compile (default-compile) on project nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors: Compilation f
ailure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPo
C-processors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[65,3
3] error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.core does not exist
[ERROR] E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPo
C-processors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[66,3
7] error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
[ERROR] E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPo
C-processors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[250,
10] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ObjectMapper
[ERROR] location: class MyProcessor
[ERROR] E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPo
C-processors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[250,
42] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ObjectMapper
[ERROR] location: class MyProcessor
[ERROR] E:\NiFi\CDCNiFi\nifi-NiFiCDCPo
C-processors\src\main\java\com\datalake\processors\MyProcessor.java:[279,
21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the below dependency in your processor (maven)project `pom.xml` is :.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: A bit strange - in Eclipse, the compilation and unit test worked without adding that, I just had the following :
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>